# Encription with chances

Tags: python

I am new to Python so help. I want it to minus the chance if the password is wrong. Its stuck on 2 if I enter a wrong password

```
while True:
    password = input("Password for activation ")
    chance = 3

    if password == "LUN":
            print("access granted")
            break

    if password != "LUN":
        wrong = chance - 1
        print("Try again. your chance is {0}".format(wrong))

    if chance == 0:
        break
```

Comment: Add `chance -= 1` inside the loop

Answer (score 3):

You have `chance = 3` inside your while loop.  So every loop, chance goes back to being 3.

Answer (score 1):

You set `chance = 3` the loop. This resets `chance` at each iteration, regardless of what else you may do.

Then, if the user guesses wrong, you set `wrong = chance - 1`. This does not change `chance` at all.

The simplest fix would be to move the initialization outside the loop, and update the correct variable:

```
chance = 3
while True:
    password = input("Password for activation ")

    if password == "LUN":
        print("access granted")
        break

    chance -= 1
    print("Try again. your chance is {0}".format(chance))

    if chance == 0:
        break
```

I also took the liberty of removing the unnecessary `if` statement.

This may be a good time to learn about `for` loops. These loops let you iterate through a collection, like a `range` of fixed size. They have another special feature, which is that they support an `else` clause that triggers whenever the loop completes normally, without a `break`:

```
for chance in range(3, -1, -1):
    password = input("Password for activation ")

    if password == "LUN":
        print("Access Granted")
        break
    print(f"Try again. You have {chance} chances left")
else:
    print("You Failed")
```